# How to control number of items per page in pagination Control php

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am wondering how can I change the default number of items per page in Zend pagination control? It is written in a phtml file as shown below. Is there an option to control the number of items by the user as in any other grid?

```
<?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->redirects, 'Sliding', 'index/page.phtml'); ?>
```

Also I created an input where the user can enter the required number of items per page but I am not able to link it with the pagination control.

```
<input type="number" min="0" value="10" id="numberOfRows">
```

I need to do something looks like that:
[image]

Comment: You need to give your input a name attribute if you want to access the value through the superglobals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);

   $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wondering how can I connect  the input value instead of using a static value such as 10

Comment: @SMH you send the value from your widget to your server and then put it into `setItemCountPerPage`. Simple as that.

Comment: @Gordon Thank you, I am sorry but I haven't done it before. Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the controller. Pass obtained database data object as the parameter to factory function.

```
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($result);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(20);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
```